# Updating TNS Entry across multiple terminals

Tags: oracle-9i

Is there anyway I could update Host in a specific TNS entry, by way of an Batch File(sqlplus via command prompt)?

A change in the IP address have been raised and we need to update the TNS across several terminals. Any easy way to handle it rather than editing the TNSnames.ora file?

Your expertise in this is very much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will do  it one time; but i suggest to use dns names entry in the tnsnames and if a change have to be made it will be on a centralized place.

Comment: Yes, I regret myself not applying DNS names, but Thanks for your suggestion; more or less it the answer way forward!